# PHP Regex Get Text Between and inside tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have this tag on an HTML code:

```
text html [button link="google.com" color="#fff" text="this text here"] rest of html
```

I wish i could have the parameters of this "button code" in a PHP variable, but have no idea how because of Regex.

I tried using **preg_match_all** but no success. Like this one:

```
preg_match_all('/color=(\w*)/i', $text, $color);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify WHAT you want out of that string

Comment: Maybe you want `if (preg_match_all('~(?:\G(?!^)|\[button)\s+(\w+)="([^"]*)"~', $text, $matches)) { print_r(array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]));}` - see https://3v4l.org/qMqXh

Comment: `\w*` won't match the `#` character in the color attribute. Or the quotes around the attribute value.

Comment: Provide expected output, please !

Comment: i wanted the link ready, sorry, i didnt type it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [preg_match_all()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
<?php

$text = 'text html [button link="google.com" color="#fff" text="this text here"] rest of html';
preg_match_all('/\[button link="(.*?)" color="(.*?)" text="(.*?)"\]/i', $text, $matches);
$link = $matches[1][0];
$color = $matches[2][0];
$text = $matches[3][0];

echo $link;
echo $color;
echo $text;
```

Output:

```
google.com
#fff
this text here
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. I will post the result that worked for me. Maybe it helps someone else! The options are already in my language, portuguese. But you can understand!

I needed the script to solve the codes for more than one tag in the same HTML.

```
$matches = [];
        preg_match_all('/\[botao link={(.*?)} texto={(.*?)} corfundo={(.*?)} corletra={(.*?)}\]/', $text, $matches);
        
        foreach($matches[0] as $key => $match) {
            $link = $matches[1][$key];
            $texto = $matches[2][$key];
            $corfundo = $matches[3][$key];
            $corletra = $matches[4][$key];
        
            $text = str_replace($match, '<a target="_blank" title="'.$texto.'" class="botao" href="'.$link.'" style="background-color: '.$corfundo.'; color: '.$corletra.';">'.$texto.'</a>', $text);
        }
```